# Web Services for Checking Malicious Domains

Tags: security, firefox, web, trust

Does anyone know of any freely available web services or APIs which accept a website URL and check this URL against a list of known malicious websites?

I was thinking of designing something similar to Web of Trust (WOT) to give you an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, you can start with Google's [Safe Browsing](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/)